# JQuery ajax chinese compatility

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i use jquery easyui datagrid to list data,and do search with it.
the jquery ajax

```
var username = $('#searchUsername').val();
var firstname = $('#searchFirstname').val();
$('#tt').datagrid({
        url: '/ajax/searchTeacher?username='+username+'&firstname='+firstname,
        title: 'search',
        width: 670,
        height: 'auto',
        fitColumns: true,
        rownumbers:true,
        singleSelect: true,
        columns:[[
                {field:'username',title:'工号',width:150},
                {field:'firstname',title:'姓名',width:150},
                {field:'academy',title:'学院',width:200},
                {field:'do',title:'操作',width:30,align:'left'}
            ]]
    });
```

but there is a compatility between IE and FF.
the url in IE:
/ajax/searchTeacher?username=&firstname=李
the url in FF:
/ajax/searchTeacher?username=&firstname=%E6%9D%8E

And it's done in FF.Apache use utf8 as default charset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use encodeURI/encodeURIComponent first before call the ajax method

e.g:

```
encodeURI("/ajax/searchTeacher?username=&firstname=李")
```

the value will be:
"/ajax/searchTeacher?username=&firstname=%E6%9D%8E"